# Previous version of PHP running during windows startup

Tags: php, reference, version, wampserver, multiple-versions

I have install PHP version 8.1.6 for my Wamp Server and when I run php -v I can verify that, but when I restart my computer a cmd window opens and it says -> wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40\php.exe

and that command window lags there for a good 2 minutes and then closes

why does it seem like this version is still being used somewhere?

Comment: Does that folder or path exist ?  If it does, you must have installed it previously.  Have you looked at the **Apps & Features** in the Settings to see if it's there ?  have you tried to remove it ?

Comment: Update environment variables

Comment: Thank you Rohit & Shozab, for your replies, yes that folder exists, it is a previous build that was used in my WampServer, I do keep all previous folder/files (versions) of PHP within my Wamp Folder but the reference in the environment variables that Shozab mentioned is updated to the new verison that I have installed, there shouldn't be another reference to the PHP 5 to make the cmd window run as far as i know and in my PHP.ini files everything now references the new PHP 8 version

Answer (score 0):

Since you can see a screen popping up, it's probably not a service.

- Start Task manager
- Click on Startup Tab
- See if you can find it here.
- Right Click on it and select "the line and select **Open File Location**
- If it's valid there will be a **Disabled** button at bottom right.

Alternatively, look in these locations

- %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp